# Select data from database and insert into dropdownlist - MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to select data from my database to insert into my dropdown list. My problem is that the dropdown list shows nothing and I don't receive any errors. Can someone give a hand with this please?

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> isto { get; set; }

 public ListagemEmpresas()
{
    isto = GetCompanies();
}

public SelectList GetCompanies()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Companieslist", con))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string id = reader[0] as string;
                string name = reader[1] as string;
                list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = name, Value = id });
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
}

public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CompanyList> abc{ get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
var dba = new DefaultConnection();
        var query = dba.abc.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.id),
            Text = c.name,

        });
        var model = new CompanyList
        {
            isto = query.AsEnumerable()
        };

        return View(model);
```

**View:**

```
@model MyProject.Models.CompanyList

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.name, Model.isto, "--Select One--")
```

Comment: You are not setting the name property for your company list. May be try setting that.

Comment: In your controller, you are only setting `isto`, but not `Name`

Comment: Post your Model completely, not just its properties. Looking at your code, it seems like the class `CompanyList` does not have a `nome_empresa' property that you are using.

Comment: @MaheshVelaga, SelectListItem does not have a Name property.

Comment: @ataravati I was referring to `CompanyList` not `SelectListItem`

Comment: @ataravati:  my fail, in the controller is the variable name.. sorry im writing the wrong.

Comment: @MaheshVelaga: hmmm.. thanks for the post.. but how i have to write this in my controller? thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you convert the Value? Why don't you just use integer?

Comment: if i not convert the value, i have the following error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` In your Controller like below. You need to convert the `DbSet<CompanyList>` to List, before you can use the `ToString()` method.

```
var query = dba.abc.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.id.ToString(),
        Text = c.name
    });
```

Then, in your View you will have (The DropDownList returns the Value of the selected item, not its Text):

```
@model MyProject.Models.CompanyList

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, Model.isto, "--Select One--")
```

Comment: Error: Can not implicity type int to string

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to convert the id to string. Also, convert abc to List, in your linq query (that's for the `ToString()` method to work). See the updated answer.

Comment: i change my code with yours. thank you very much for this. but i can´t understand why i still not receive any data from my database.

Comment: So, you don't have a problem with the DropDownList, but with pooling data from database, right? What does `dba.abc` return?

Comment: return nothing.. im so confused.. im trying and trying a lot of things, but still not receive nothing... :(

Comment: ataravati: i think so.. the problem are to receive the data from database

Comment: i use a sqlserver where are my database.. i have add a connectionstring to my web config to access

Comment: First of all, I recommend that you use Entity Framework. Are you sure there's data in your database table? I think you should ask a separate question and provide more information about your database connection (your connection string in the web.config file, your DAL,...).

Comment: yes i have check if exists data in the table..ok ataravati thanks for the help